# Ubuntu server 18.04, Dynamic DNS w/google domains - mydomain.com resolves, www.mydomain.com does not

Tags: apache2, dns, virtualhost, dynamic-ip, ddclient

My problem is this - I don't know the best way to end-to-end troubleshoot this dynamic dns setup and hosting.

Essentially what I want to is use the google domains dynamic dns service to forward http requests to my router IP and then have those requests directed to my server (local IP 192.168.1.4).

- going to http://mydomain.com ~ Works! (NS lookup to public server resolves)
- going to http://www.mydomain.com ~ Fails! (NS lookup to public server fails)

**What I have setup**

First I setup the Ubuntu 18.04 server.
Then I setup apache with a virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is on a local home network, server has local static IP.

I have ddclient running updating Google Domains for dynamic DNS:

```
# Configuration file for ddclient generated by debconf
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf
daemon=300
syslog=yes
protocol=dyndns2
ssl=yes
use=web
web=ip.changeip.com
server=domains.google.com
login=*****************
password='*****************'
jimconnors.us
```

Then on my local router I setup a DNS rule:

```
Hostname: mydomain.com
IP address: 192.168.1.4
```

I don't know where I am screwing up, and with all the moving parts, I wanted to ask before I started monkeying with one config after another.

I would like to be able to resolve subdomains; app1.mydomain.com, app2.mydomain.com.

I don't know if I need to specify more synthetic records in google domains, format a wildcard DNS entry in my ddclient config.  Any guidance - even just troubleshooting step advice would be very much appreciated.

Jim

Comment: did you also set up a dynamic dns entry on your system for your subdomains as well?  You need to set *every* dynamic DNS updated 'target' properly, that includes your domain and subdomain names.  Otherwise, it won't add public DNS for www, etc. (www is also a subdomain by the way)

Comment: @ThomasWard, if I understand what you are saying, I need to create a record for each subdomain I am looking to have it resolve.  With each 'Synthetic Record' I create on google domains ( @ mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com, ftp.mydomain.com) it gives me different credentials (uname/pwd). How would I setup each of those in the ddclient.conf?

Comment: No, set up 'dns records' in the cloud to be CNAMEs of the *specific* dynamic DNS your system is, if possible.  They'll resolve to the same IP that way.

Comment: So for say www.mydomain.com and ftp.mydomain.com, setup a CNAME record for each that points to the naked domain?  mydomain.com?

Comment: correct, that would achieve the same goal.  that way you only need to update the bare domain and the IP resolutions for subdomains update too